# Hiding the div on page load

Tags: javascript, html

> person.jsp

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateadvance() {
            document.getElementById("fn").style.visibility = "visible";
            }

        $(function() {
            $(".dp").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>

             <table border="1" width="500" align="center">
                <tr>
                                 <td>
                                     <div id="left-pane"
                            style="float: left; width: 20%; padding-bottom: 350px">
                            <a href="person.jsp">Candidate_Details</a> <br> <a
                                href="jobsearch.jsp">Technical_Details</a> <br>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div id="left-pane">
                            <br>
                            <br> ID <input type=text value="" maxlength="10" size="10">
                            <br>
                            <br> Name <select>
                                <option value="start">Startswith</option>
                                <option value="end">Endswith</option>
                                <option value="exact">Exact</option>
                                <option value="anywhere">Anywhere</option>
                            </select> <input type=text value=""> <br>
                            <br> Batch <select>
                                <option value="completed">JINIS Group</option>
                                <option value="intensionally quit">Brigade Group</option>
                                <option value="incomplete">Apurva Batch</option>
                                <option value="not taken">TCS Group</option>
                                <option value="all">All</option>
                            </select> <br>
                            <br> Test_Status <select>
                                <option value="approved">Approved</option>
                                <option value="onhold">On_Hold</option>
                                <option value="pending">Pending</option>
                                <option value="rejected">Rejected</option>
                            </select> <br>
                            <br>


                            <div id="fn" class="hidethis" style="visibility: 'hidden'">

                                Email <select>
                                    <option value="start">Startswith</option>
                                    <option value="end">Endswith</option>
                                    <option value="exact">Exact</option>
                                    <option value="anywhere">Anywhere</option>
                                </select> <input type=text value=""> <br>
                                <br> Password <select>
                                    <option value="start">Startswith</option>
                                    <option value="end">Endswith</option>
                                    <option value="exact">Exact</option>
                                    <option value="anywhere">Anywhere</option>
                                </select> <input type=text value=""> <br>
                                <br> Job Processed <select>
                                    <option value="businessman">Businessman</option>
                                    <option value="ceo">CEO of the company</option>
                                    <option value="design manager">Design Manager</option>
                                    <option value="project leader">Project Leader</option>
                                </select> <br>
                                <br> Pdf_Export <input type="radio" name="pdf_export"
                                    value="yes">Yes <input type="radio" name="pdf_export"
                                    value="no">No <input type="radio" name="pdf_export"
                                    value="no">Both <br>
                                <br> Technical_TestStatus <select>
                                    <option value="completed">Completed</option>
                                    <option value="intensionally quit">Intentionally Quit</option>
                                    <option value="incomplete">Incomplete</option>
                                    <option value="not taken">Not Taken</option>
                                </select> <br>
                                <br> Test Inconsistency<br> <input type="checkbox"
                                    name="inconsistency" value="yes">Yes <input
                                    type="checkbox" name="inconsistency" value="no">No <input
                                    type="checkbox" name="inconsistency" value="no">Ok <br>
                                <br> Date_of_Test <input type="text" id="datepicker"
                                    class="dp" size="8" /> - <input type="text" id="datepicker1"
                                    class="dp" size="8" />
                            </div>

                            <div id="left-pane" align="center">

                                <br>
                                <br> <input type="button" value="Search"
                                    style="width: 130px; height: 35px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <input
                                    type="button" value="AdvancedSearch"
                                    onclick="return validateadvance()"
                                    style="width: 130px; height: 35px;" />
                            </div>
                    </td>
                             </tr>
            </table>

        </form>
    </body>
```

//When i am running the code in eclipse, at start div having id "fn" is hidden and onclick of advancesearch the div is visible but when running it in browser div is visible when the page loads.
So please can anyone help me how the div can be made hidden at start and visible on button click even in browser.

Comment: just use `style="visibility: hidden"`. Remove single quote in hidden

Comment: this change is not helpfull--Tamil Selvan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure to execute your JavaScript only after the DOM has been loaded. Otherwise, the JavaScript will run before the `div` has even been loaded onto the page. To do this using jQuery, you may simply wrap your existing code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ... your JS code ...
});
```

… and that should do it.

But also, you need to hide it. That means setting visibility to `hidden`, not `visible`.

Answer (score 0):

try this style

```
//html
<div id="fn" class="hidethis" style="display: none;">

//javascript
function validateadvance() {
    document.getElementById("fn").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validateadvance() {
            document.getElementById("fn").style.visibility = "visible";

        }

        $(function() {
            $(".dp").datepicker();
            document.getElementById("fn").style.visibility = "hidden";
        });
    </script>
```